# Formulas not calculating in manual mode in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have had to set Excel to manual mode due to the nature of the computation I will be doing. I have also enabled iterative calculations.

I created a created a row of values (0 to 14) and, in the row above, I set in a simple formula in the first column ($"=x_0+B12*(x_1-x_0)/N_"$ where all of the parameters have been defined and given a value. I obtained the excepted value of 0 in the first column, however when I dragged the formula across I obtained 0 in all of the other rows.

I thought this is probably to do with the manual setting. I tried pressing F9 and this just logged me out of my laptop. I tried SHIFT+F9, CTRL+F9, CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F9.... essentially every combination of these, however the values still remain as zero. In fact, I can only make them calculate the value they should be if I click into a cell, click into the formula bar at the top (which displays the correct formula) and press enter. It does not suffice to press enter when I have just clicked on the cell itself.

I am using Excel 2016. The only solutions I found on the web were using the F9 key, and it seemed to work for the OPs. Any ideas would be most welcome.

EDIT: Just to add, when I do press SHIFT+F9, I just get the letter L appearing in the highlighted cell. I have tried with Num Lock on and off.

Comment: can you just click the button: `Calculate Sheet` ? does it work then ?

Comment: If you are using a laptop key board there is a good chance that you do not have the fnlock set.  try Fn-F9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PeterH suggested, In the **Formulas** tab in the Ribbon try clicking **Calculate Now**. It's all the way on the right.